# Android seekbar with wide custom thumb doesn't line up horizontally through the whole bar

Tags: android, user-interface, seekbar

I am trying to create a seek bar with quite a wide thumb on top. Unfortunately, I am unable to get the thumb lined up through the whole movement of the progress bar. I can get it to line up at 50% but it's behind the thumb at anything less and in front at anything more. I have the following code:

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/mediacontroller_progress"
    style="@style/CustomVideoProgressBarHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="36dp"
    android:alpha="0.94"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:progress="50"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/customvideoprogressbar"
    android:thumb="@drawable/ic_media_stars" />
```

And this is what I'm seeing at 50%:

[image: Perfect]

at 20%:

[image: Behind!]

at 80%:
[image: Ahead!]

Is there a better way to position this thumb? The thumboffset property allows me to line it up at the start or the end but doesn't help it track at all.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem? Facing the same issue!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `android:thumbOffset="0dp"`